# Vlookup in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, vlookup

I just started leaning python... I have two dataframes the df1 consists of "article number" and "current tier". The df2 consists of "article number" and "updated tier". The rows in both dataframes is not same. I want to the output that shows the "article numbers" where the updated tier is 'different' than current tire

I am trying to use join or merge, could not figure out.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! here are the guidelines about asking questions  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: one other way is to map the values from DF2 into DF1 and then filter out where current and updated tier mismatches